# How to arrange data in proper format

Tags: android, asp.net-web-api

I am getting response from my service in this format:

```
<ArrayOfEvents xmlns:i="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"  
xmlns="http://schemas.datacontract.org/2004/07/ClassLibrary1">
<Events>
<Comp_Name>abcd</Comp_Name>
<DateOF_Event>*****</DateOF_Event>
<EVENT_DATE>*****</EVENT_DATE>
<Event_Location>*****</Event_Location>
<Evnet_id>****</Evnet_id>
<HetUid>****</HetUid>
<Job_Desc>...</Job_Desc>
<Position_Name>****</Position_Name>
</Events>
<Events>
<Comp_Name>****</Comp_Name>
<DateOF_Event>*****</DateOF_Event>
<EVENT_DATE>*****</EVENT_DATE>
<Event_Location>*****</Event_Location>
<Evnet_id>****</Evnet_id>
<HetUid>****</HetUid>
<Job_Desc>...</Job_Desc>
<Position_Name>*****</Position_Name>
</Events>

</ArrayOfEvents>
```

I want to use this response in my android app,how to arrange it in proper format.

Comment: you have to parse it first. you have to check xml parsing in android

Comment: see this link it helps you.http://www.androidhive.info/2011/11/android-xml-parsing-tutorial/

Comment: @tiya if you use .net webservice then you have to use Soap serialization